# Is there a chance of reading 16-bytes /dev/urandom data twice, and getting same result?

Tags: linux, math, random

Working with Linux 3.2, I would like to implement a UID algorithm using `/dev/urandom`.

There may be a chance of reading 16 random bytes twice, and getting the same result. But is the chance small enough to be negligible?

Comment: Keep on mind that a uuid is not just random bits. If you're making a version four uuid there has to be a four in the version field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dev/urandom` is supposed to be a random device that *should* look uniformly random, and in a uniformly random sequence you would expect to find repeated patterns.  However, since there are 2<sup>128</sup> possible 16-byte sequences, this should happen with probability 2<sup>-128</sup>, which is vanishingly small.

That said, `/dev/urandom` is not known to be cryptographically safe and there may be attacks that aren't in the open literature to force the behavior to degenerate (perhaps some government agency knows how to do this, for example).  From the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html):

> A read from the /dev/urandom device will not block waiting for more
>          entropy.  As a result, if there is not sufficient entropy in the
>          entropy pool, **the returned values are theoretically vulnerable to a
>          cryptographic attack on the algorithms used by the driver.  Knowledge
>          of how to do this is not available in the current unclassified
>          literature,** but it is theoretically possible that such an attack may
>          exist.  If this is a concern in your application, use /dev/random
>          instead.

(My emphasis) Therefore, I wouldn't rely on this if you are trying to go for cryptographic security.

In short, if you just need random values, this is probably fine.  If you want to go for cryptographic security, I would not recommend doing this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `/dev/urandom` is specifically provided for cases where you need cryptographic security. (You do have to make sure the pool is seeded at some point.)

Comment: thanks, 1/2^-128 sounds small enough to be negligible, I do not quite need cryptographic randomness, it sounds good enough for UID.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz- I think that's `/dev/random`.  Or am I misreading the link I posted?

Comment: @templatetypedef `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` have nearly identical behavior. The differences are subtle and which one you want depends on many factors. They will both provide cryptographically-secure randomness if properly used and most actual crypto applications use `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz- From my understanding, every bit of data in `/dev/random` comes from an entropy accumulator, which in principle should be indistinguishable from random.  `/dev/urandom` works the same way, but if it runs out of data it uses predictable algorithms to extend the data.  Consequently, it behaves more like a stream cipher, which could be attacked if too much data is used and the seed is controllable in some way.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: @templatetypedef It's correct. But a car *could* blow up and kill you. That doesn't mean it's unsuitable for traveling to work. For most cryptographic applications, `/dev/urandom` is suitable and the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

you have a 1/2^128 chance of reading the same data, so yes - the probability is very negligible. Roughly the same probability of breaking the AES128 encryption scheme.

Comment: thanks, after reading some materials describing linux RNG internals, i learned that even the nonblocking RNG pool is of very high quality.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are perfectly random, due to the [Birthday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) the probability is approximately 2<sup>-64</sup> (the square root of getting any particular value).  That is, at about 2<sup>64</sup> UIDs, the probability to find a pair becomes greater than 50%.

For most applications that should be fine.